# Linux: how can echo disable '\t'?

Tags: linux

I want to have exactly as follows:

```
 cut -d$'\t' test1.txt 
 cut -d$'\t' test2.txt
```

using:

```
for i in 1 2; do
  echo "cut -d$'\t' test$i.txt"
done
```

but it turned out:

```
cut -d$' ' test1.txt
cut -d$' ' test2.txt
```

how can i get '\t' from echo? Thanks

Comment: Works fine in my bash. What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` may or may not respect or expand flags or escape sequences. `printf` doesn't have this undefined behavior. If you want an exact output, just stay away from `echo` entirely. Also, you should escape any special characters like `$` and `\` for good measure:

```
for i in 1 2
do
  printf "%s\n" "cut -d\$'\\t' test$i.txt"
done
```

By the way, this is a really bad starting point if you want to process `test*.txt` files with `cut`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can get it right using your code.  You are right that it is a bad start to use cut. But it is the only way I can think of, I just need to use "echo" to generate a lot of similar short scripts then use "cut".

Comment: @Ming it's a bad start to generate commands as text output. They should be commands, not text.

Comment: so what is the proper way to generate similar commands? so that I can use the output of the commands to another command? i am currently doing a lot of work like that.

Comment: @Ming If you want to run these commands, you should use e.g. `for i in 1 2; do cut -d $'\t' -f 1 "test$i.txt"; done` with no `printf`. Going through printf makes it harder and more insecure because you have to account for additional escaping.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helps a lot.